# HttpWebRequest setting host to garbage but still getting OK response

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using an HttpWebRequest and passing in an Address which is an IP.  I then set the host to a garbage value.  When I call `GetResponse()` I am getting an OK even though I would expect this to fail since the host is garbage.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("http://10.10.10.10/Default.aspx"));
request.Host = "blah.blah.blah";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { /*always enters here */ }
}
```

Why is the response coming back as OK?  Shouldn't the garbage host cause this to fail?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that could be eating the bad requests and showing an error page, or redirecting you elsewhere?

Comment: (And as an addendum to that comment, what is the returned in the response? Dump the response stream to a string and analyze it.)

Comment: Behind a proxy but no error page.  If I type http://blah.blah.blah into IE I get dns_server_failure.

Comment: I've also noticed various ISP/DNS servers now redirect invalid URL's somewhere else (not returning 404), definitely dump the page and view the results.

Comment: Error could also be caused because ".blah" is an invalid domain suffix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HttpWebRequest.Host Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx):

> Get or set the Host header value to use in an HTTP request independent from the request URI.
>
> Using the Host property to explicitly specify a custom Host header value also affects areas caching, cookies, and authentication. When an application provides credentials for a specific URI prefix, the applications needs to make sure to use the URI containing the value of the Host header, not the target server in the URI.

So there is no effect of `.Host` to the general request, you change some additional behavior.